# Rewrite Condition Rule for JIRA ServiceDesk

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, jira

Atlassian JIRA's Service Desk plugin portal has it's ugly url, users must remember this long URL

http://jira.domain.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/1

For my users i would like to have special domain :

http://helpdesk.domain.com/

Task is not so simple, i need rewrite url in Apache

```
http://helpdesk.domain.com/ --- > http://jira.domain.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/1
```

but need to exclude

```
http://helpdesk.domain.com/s/files.css ---> http://jira.domain.com/s/files.css
http://helpdesk.domain.com/rest/myjson ---> http://jira.domain.com/rest/myjson
http://helpdesk.domain.com/secure/some.html ---> http://jira.domain.com/secure/some.html
```

Comment: Did you get this to work in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine something like this:

```
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}  !/helpdesk.domain.com/s/files.css 
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}  !/helpdesk.domain.com/rest/myjson
ReWriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}  !/helpdesk.domain.com/secure/some.html
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?helpdesk\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$          http://jira.domain.com/servicedesk/customer/portal/1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```